# VB.NET event handler name prefix

Tags: vb.net

In ASP.NET - when selecting the Load event in Visual Studio - the designer generates Page_Load as the Sub name for the event handler. How can I do something similar with custom events ?

When I select a custom event in Visual Studio is prefixes the Sub name with the name of the class. So if my custom event is named say "Delete" and the class name is ManageRoom it will generate Sub ManageRoom_Delete() Handles ...

Is there a way to set it up so that the prefix it uses is something other than the class name ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Visual Studio extension [EventHandlerNaming](https://github.com/einaregilsson/EventHandlerNaming)

From the [homepage](http://einaregilsson.com/better-eventhandler-names-in-visual-studio-2010/):

> I made a Visual Studio extension, EventHandler Naming, that lets you customize generated eventhandler names and use delegate inference.

[image]

I don't know if it works for Visual Basic, but it's the only one I know.

Comment: Hmm - will check it out. Was hoping something simple like adding an attribute to the event declaration.